# Sort a 2d array by two columns, both descending

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I need to sort array (lower) by the value of [price] BUT if value of [stock] = 0, I need to sort them too, but they should be placed lower than those where [stock] > 0. The function has to be for any number of subarrays, the array lower is only example.

I have array

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [cardname] => Tundra Wolves
        [edition] => Legends
        [stock] => 0
        [price] => 5
        [shop] => cernyrytir.cz
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [cardname] => Tundra Wolves
        [edition] => Legends
        [stock] => 20
        [price] => 9
        [shop] => mysticshop.cz
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [cardname] => Tundra Wolves
        [edition] => Legends
        [stock] => 5
        [price] => 5
        [shop] => najada.cz
    )
    
[3] => Array
    (
        [cardname] => Tundra Wolves
        [edition] => Legends
        [stock] => 0
        [price] => 3
        [shop] => rishada.cz
    )
)
```

I need array:

```
Array
(
[2] => Array
    (
        [cardname] => Tundra Wolves
        [edition] => Legends
        [stock] => 5
        [price] => 5
        [shop] => najada.cz
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [cardname] => Tundra Wolves
        [edition] => Legends
        [stock] => 20
        [price] => 9
        [shop] => mysticshop.cz
    )
    
[3] => Array
    (
        [cardname] => Tundra Wolves
        [edition] => Legends
        [stock] => 0
        [price] => 3
        [shop] => rishada.cz
    )

[0] => Array
    (
        [cardname] => Tundra Wolves
        [edition] => Legends
        [stock] => 0
        [price] => 5
        [shop] => cernyrytir.cz
    )
)
```

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better

Comment: You might be looking for the [uasort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) function.

Comment: @JoshuaDwire was just about to post this, I agree.

Comment: It's easy to sort array. I have a lot of work with grouping done. I can sort the array by [price][stock], but it doesn't do what I mean and I really do not know how to ensures, that those arrays with [stock] will be sorted by [price] too but placed after those where [stock] > 0 in the same time. Yes, I can use two field and separate those with [stock]=0 and those with [stock] > 0, then sort them and merge them, but it's really ugly solution

Comment: well add that solution to your question.

Comment: No, don't add solutions to questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, this is what you want then:

```
foreach($a as $key => $value) {
    if ($value['stock'] > 0) {
        $stock[] = $value;
        $stockPrice[] = $value['price'];
    } else {
        $zeroStock[] = $value;
        $zeroStockPrice[] = $value['price'];
    }
}

array_multisort($stockPrice, SORT_ASC, $stock);
array_multisort($zeroStockPrice, SORT_ASC, $zeroStock);

$array = array_merge($stock, $zeroStock);
```

Now $array has what you want.

Comment: Still have a problem. I don't want only order by two fields, I need order by [price] of those, where [stock] > 0 and after them order by [price] where [stock] = 0. It's still giving me the result order by stock. Try to replace in subarray [1] the value to 20. (Changed the question to simulate this)

Comment: Man, seems that it works like a charm. Thank you very much. Now I see, it's not so horribly difficult, but I really can't figure it out. Thanks once again, great job.

Answer (score 2):

```
function cmp($a, $b) {

    if($a['stock'] == 0 && $b['stock'] != 0) 
        return -1;

    if($b['stock'] == 0 && $a['stock'] != 0) 
        return 1;

    if ($a['price'] == $b['price']) 
        return 0;


    return ($a['price'] < $b['price']) ? -1 : 1;
}



uasort($productsArr , 'cmp');
```

This should work. First you compare price, second you compare stocks.

Comment: `uasort` is not stable, so you can't just apply one sorting function then another and expect the right result. You need _one_ sorting function that considers both properties.

Comment: Yes! You're right. I edited the answer and now will work good. Thanks for hint.

Comment: Looks much better, but still have one problem. Occurred with two subarrays, first have [stock] = 0, [price] = 45 and second [stock] = 1, [price] = 39. The first one appears still as first (but have [stock] = 0, so should be the second).

Answer (score 1):

`array_multisort()`  look at the example of `foreach` and save two arrays $stock and $price and use those to sort the main array.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $row) {
    $stock[$key]  = $row['stock'];
    $price[$key] = $row['price'];
}
//adjust to fit asc or desc
array_multisort($price, SORT_DESC, $stock, SORT_DESC, $array);
```

Comment: Alternatively, if this is coming from a db, sort on price and stock in the query.

Comment: No, it's not coming from DB, it would be much easier. 

Still have a problem. I don't want only order by two fields, I need order by [price] of those, where [stock] > 0 and after them order by [price] where [stock] = 0.